# Swift : Does hiding an animating view still affect memory/performance?

Tags: ios, swift, performance, memory

### In my projects, i have a little trick to create a loading view :

- Creating a *UIView* and set its constraints (theLoadingView)
- Placing a *UIActivityIndicatorView* inside theLoadingView
- Make this activity indicator always animating (set the flag to true)
- Showing theLoadingView Before any operation
- Hiding theLoadingView when operation is done

### This is working awesome but i am wondering does that affect memory/performance ?

Cause of the activity indicator is always animating even when hiding theLoadingView ! Should i stop activity indicator animation before hiding theLoadingView ?

**Here is a screen shot :**

[image]

Welcome to all opinions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: short answer -> yes it is impacting performance
long answer ->  depending on what your app does, the performance impact is probably irrelevant.  your approach works, but it's not a great solution. create an extension for `UIViewController` and add a function which starts the activity indicator and one which stops it. this way the activity indicator will be available in every `ViewController`

Comment: I need to display my custom view not just an activity indicator !

Answer (score -1):

If you just set that `loadingView` isHidden property to true , this only hide that `loadingView` in super view , and that `loadingView` is allocated memory in background till you remove that from super view !

I suggest you to :

- give that loadingView a tag ; in prefer 2018 :D
- find loadingView with tag 2018 in super view
- remove loadingView from super view

  ```
  let loadingView = self.view.viewWithTag(2018)
  loadingView.removeFromSuperview()
  ```

Comment: I don't want to remove it ! Because i am using it for any operation in the view controller.